# Через некоторое время перестают доставляться сообщения через RabbitMQ подписчику

Tags: c#, golang, rabbitmq

У нас есть очерез сообщений RabbitMQ, в которой создаются очереди для подписчиков, к которым они подписываются и обмениваются сообщениями.
После создания канала сообщения доставляются как нужно, но через некоторое время (2-3 суток) они перестают доходить до подписчика.
Вопрос - как можно отловить причину такого поведения? я создаю канал таким способом:

```
chnl, errCreateChannel := structs.RabbitMQ.Channel()
if errCreateChannel != nil {
    log.Printf("Ошибка создания канала в RabbitMQ: %s", errCreateChannel.Error())
    return
}
errNotifyClose := chnl.NotifyClose(make(chan *amqp.Error, 10))
go func() {
    for errClose := range errNotifyClose {
        if errClose != nil {
            sentry.CaptureException(errClose)
        }
    }
}()

defer chnl.Close()

_, errQueueDeclare := chnl.QueueDeclare(robotUID+"-Server", false, true, false, false, nil)
if errQueueDeclare != nil {
    log.Printf("Ошибка соединения с очередью %s в RabbitMQ: %s", robotUID+"-Server", errQueueDeclare.Error())
    return
}

msgs, errConsume := chnl.Consume(robotUID+"-Server", "", true, false, false, false, nil)
if errConsume != nil {
    log.Printf("Ошибка получений сообщений с очереди %s в RabbitMQ: %s", robotUID+"-Server", errConsume.Error())
    return
}
```

Затем подписчик соединяется с каналом таким способом:

```
_connection = factory.CreateConnection();
_channel = _connection.CreateModel();
_channel.QueueDeclare(_cmd.Rmq.Queue, false, false, true, null);

var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
consumer.Received += (_, ea) => { HandleMessage(ea); };
_channel.BasicConsume(_cmd.Rmq.Queue, true, consumer);
```

Я добавил NotifyClose для получения сообщений о закрытии канала сегодня, и попытаюсь отловить если в канале происходят закрытия из-за ошибки. Какие еще есть варианты для отслеживания этого поведения?

P.S после перезапуска Go приложения, где создаются очереди, сообщения начинают доходить до подписчиков, поэтому есть подозрение что теряется связь из приложения с RabbitMQ сервисом.

Comment: Кролик умеет логи писать, насколько я помню. А где живет подписчик, что за хост? Есть вероятность, что хостер его усыпляет как неактивного, и нужно heartbeat настраивать.

Comment: heartbeat вряд ли нужен так как подписчик регулярно, каждые 30 секунд, отправляет свое состояние приложению на Go. Подписчик живет в другом процессе и окружении, все подписчики и хост в облаке K8s.

Comment: Это зависит от хостера, на что он реагирует, когда поддерживает лайфтайм сервера

Comment: @aepot имеете в виду хост как OS подписчика, которая усыпляет его? Вряд ли, в K8S такого нет, процесс запущен и работает, по логам подписчика вижу что работа идёт. Или вы имеете в виду что-то что закрывает его связь с очередью отсылателя? Возможно, так как сообщения от отсылателя приходят очень редко ...

Comment: В общем, убедитесь, что ничего нигде не засыпает. Индикатор - фиксированное время от старта до сна, при нормальной работе.